# Shortcut to go to the first and last frame of a selected NLA Strip

Tags: shortcut, customization, nla-editor

I know there is a shortcut to go at the first frame (by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>←</kbd>) and to go at the last frame (by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) in the timeline.

I want to know if there is any shortcut to go to the first and last frame of a selected NLA Strip? I was also trying to add a shortcut, although, no such provision was found to add shortcut in this regard.

Comment: I see some variation of your goal in the Suggestion box (rightclickselect) at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/M9gbbc

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I was finding some different solution for my question.